# Python write newline without \n

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, text, append

Hey I need to write a string to a text file but i need it to not have a \n as I am using it as a database. The script works fine but doesnt actually write into a newline obviously because I strip()-ed it. I was wondering if there was a way around even in another language.
So far I tried:

```
textfile = open('pass.txt.','a')
ask = raw_input("[+] Do you want to append you own passwords(y/n)")
if ask == "y":
    print "[+] Use quit_appender_now to quit adding string"
    while True:
        stri = raw_input("[+] Enter word to add-->")
        if stri == "quit_appender_now":
            break
        else:
            stri = stri + "\n"
            textfile.write(stri.strip())
elif ask =="n":
    pass
```

The reason I dont want to use \n is because of this code:

```
with open('pass.txt'),'r') as r_text:
    for x in r_text:
        print repr(x)
```

The above code will print out the string with \n. Is there any way to get around this?
For example if pass.txt had asdf in there print repr(x) would print asdf\n. I need it to print asdf

Comment: "If you want your data to show up on different 'lines', you must put a line separator between them. That's all that the '\n' character is." Read the whole answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18065656/2039173

Comment: Nah I coded the second just to illustrate my point. The real reason is much more complex and that would'nt solve it

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam Thanks makes sense thanks. I just will have to find another way to make it work. Would any other language be able to make this work? I know some basic assembly and C, and alright at Java. Assembly I know is really really basic. Like hello world basic but i could always get stuff from the internet.

Comment: Just a remark `stri = stri + "\n"` followed with `stri = stri.strip()` is no-op since the `\n` will be removed by the strip. But please say what is the real problem you are trying to solve instead of letting us guess. As you are speaking of *database* maybe a fixed size record file would better fit than a line oriented one.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The OP is looking for a way to encode line breaks in data fields into a textfile that has line breaks as a record separator. Some crude form of CSV. I would recommend to simply use CSV instead of rolling your own serialization format.

Comment: What about `stri = stri + chr(10)` is it same as "\n" ??

Comment: @SubinThomas Yeah it is same

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve from your (current) problem description, but I suspect that this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Isitha, obviously you didn't understand what Daniel wrote. This has nothing to do with the language you use, it's about how text files work. Study the answer he pointed you to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you are asking for is impossible because a newline **is** `\n`!

To clarify, text files contain sequences of characters. The only way to divide them into lines is to use one or more characters as the end-of-line marker. That's all `\n` is. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065656/2039173), suggested by [@Daniel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317233/python-write-newline-without-n/33317588#comment54432533_33317233), for more details.)

So you can write without newlines, but your file will be one loooong line. If you want to display its contents with `repr()` but don't like seeing the newline, you'll have to strip it before you print it:

```
with open('pass.txt'),'r') as r_text:
    for x in r_text:
        x = x.rstrip("\n")   # Don't discard spaces, if any
        print repr(x)
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, then your problem really has no solution and you need to ask a different question about the ultimate purpose of the file you're trying to generate. Someone will point you to a solution other than "writing a newline without writing a newline".

Answer (score 0):

You could make a definition to write a line to a file.
For example:

```
class Dummy():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello')
        self.writeToFile('Writing a line')
        self.writeToFile('Writing another line')

    def writeToFile(self, value):
        self.value = value 
        # Open file 
        file = open('DummyFile.txt', 'a')
        # Write value to file. 
        file.write(value)
        # Jump to a new line. 
        file.write('\n')
        # close file 
        file.close()

Dummy()
```

If you then would read `DummyFile.txt`, you will not see the `\n` in the text.